# Didn't get any dynamic content on web page using view/template engine (Handlebars)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, backend, handlebars.js

I am using Handlebars template engine. Not getting any error at console but I am not able to display dynamic content in the index.hbs file which is rendered from app.js

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.set('view engine','hbs');   

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));   //to get the html form data

app.use(express.static('./public'));

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    
    res.render('index.hbs'); 

});

app.post('/', async (req,res)=>{

   const currentCity = req.body.city; 
   
   let WRAP_DATA = await getCityWeather(currentCity);  //getCityWeather function return weather by city
   
   console.log('Weather Info = ',WRAP_DATA); // successfully got the WRAP_DATA 
   
   res.render('index.hbs',{WRAP_DATA});
});
```

At console I got WRAP_DATA successfully

```
description: 'overcast clouds',
humidity: 53,
visibility: 10,
windSpeed: 2.592,
winddeg: 32
```

index.hbs

"It is located inside view folder and display HTML&CSS properly only problem is replacing dynamic data". I am mentioning code where I used hbs {{ }} tags only.

```
<table>
                <tr class="detail">
                    <td> <img src="../img/humidity.png" class="desc_icon"> </td>
                    <td class="label">Humidity</td>
                    <td class="value"> {{ WRAP_DATA.humidity }} %</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="detail">
                    <td> <img src="../img/visibility.png" class="desc_icon"> </td>
                    <td class="label">Visibility</td>
                    <td class="value"> {{ WRAP_DATA.visibility }} km</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="detail">
                    <td> <img src="../img/windspeed.png" class="desc_icon"> </td>
                    <td class="label">Wind Speed</td>
                    <td class="value"> {{ WRAP_DATA.windSpeed }} km/h</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="detail">
                    <td> <img src="../img/direction.png" class="desc_icon"> </td>
                    <td class="label">Wind Direction</td>
                    <td class="value"> {{ WRAP_DATA.winddeg }} °</td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

when I run my project my backend works fine but above mentioned WRAP_DATA values are not displaying at their position in index.hbs

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix your code there are two main rendering concept you need to understand first.

1. **Server-side rendering**: this is when you make a request to the server and the whole HTML is sent back for viewing in the browser. Templating packages like Handlebars, EJS and Pug are great for this because if you have dynamic content you just pass the data to the view file and the templating package takes the values out of your data object and puts them in their placeholders in the HTML. Once that is done it sends the HTML file to the browser. Your users see the finished product with these new values. You request a route and get back HTML. Very simple.
2. **Client-side rendering**: this is a bit more complex. You still request the route like above but this time there is no templating packages like Handlebars, EJS and Pug. Your route handlers send back a minimal HTML and you make API requests for the data. The API requests are typically made via Axios or fetch and your server usually responds with JSON data. It is then up to you to take the values out of the data object and render them in your minimal HTML file. This is done in the browser, not on the server. Packages such as React/Vue/Angular can be leveraged here because they were designed to work under this pattern.

Read more [here](https://web.dev/articles/rendering-on-the-web).

In your codebase you have a mix of two. That is why you don't see the `WRAP_DATA` being displayed. There is nothing wrong with using both patterns and many web apps do this. Your problem is that you havn't done either properly.

**How can you fix?**

The ***first option*** is to not send the `fetch` request. Instead just submit the form to the server, which will be **server-side rendering**. Change your `index.hbs` to this:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="search">
        <form action="/" method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter City" name="cityName">
            <button type="submit" class="button-icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>
    </div>
    {{#if WRAP_DATA }}
        <div class="weather">
            <table class="table_Temp">
                <tr>
                    <td id="iconImage"> 
                        <img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/ {{ WRAP_DATA.iconId }} @2x.png" class="weather_icon"> 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <h3 class="description">{{ WRAP_DATA.description }}</h3>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> 
                        <h1 class="temp" id="tempId">{{ WRAP_DATA.temp }} °C</h1> 
                    </td>
                    <td> 
                        <h2 class="city" id="cityId">{{ WRAP_DATA.cityName }}, {{ WRAP_DATA.country }}</h2> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="details">
            <table>
                <tr class="detail">
                    <td> <img src="/images/humidity.png" class="desc_icon" alt="humidity-icon"> </td> 
                    <td class="label">Humidity</td>
                    
                    <td class="value"> {{ WRAP_DATA.humidity }} %</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="detail">
                    <td> <img src="/images/visibility.png" class="desc_icon"> </td>
                    <td class="label">Visibility</td>
                    <td class="value"> {{ WRAP_DATA.visibility }} km</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="detail">
                    <td> <img src="/images/windspeed.png" class="desc_icon"> </td>
                    <td class="label">Wind Speed</td>
                    <td class="value"> {{ WRAP_DATA.windSpeed }} km/h</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="detail">
                    <td> <img src="/images/direction.png" class="desc_icon"> </td>
                    <td class="label">Wind Direction</td>
                    <td class="value"> {{ WRAP_DATA.winddeg }} °</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    {{/if}}
</div>
```

Change your `app.post('/')` response to this:

```js
res.render('index.hbs', {WRAP_DATA: WRAP_DATA});
```

---

The ***second option*** involves a fair bit more work. I can see you want to send the geo-loation via fetch. In this scenario your `index.hbs` will look like this, give your form a name like `name="cityForm"`:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="search">
        <form action="/" method="post" name="cityForm">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter City" name="cityName">
            <button type="submit" class="button-icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then when your form submits you will need to listen for it using JavaScript and then send the request via fetch. Something like this in your `main.hbs`:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form[name="cityForm"]');
if(form !== null){
    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        // Get your values form the form
        // Get your geo-location
        // Send the fetch quest with the body: JSON.stringify(yourData)
        // Loop through the JSON response
        // Add elements to the DOM
    });
}
```

Your `app.post('/')` route would then need to respond like this:

```js
res.status(200).json(WRAP_DATA);
```

Clearly in the second option you will need to do a lot more research into how you can add HTML to the DOM yourself using the JSON object and how to use fetch properly. If you go for this approach Stack Overflow has lots of questions and answers regrading these concepts and as long as you trust yourself and not give up, then you will be able to learn them. Good luck with your project.

Comment: I followed first option and didn't get WRAP_DATA in the index.hbs

Comment: I copied all your files and tested it to make sure it worked. Did you copy the `index.hbs` exactly like it is above and send the `res.render('index.hbs', {WRAP_DATA: WRAP_DATA});`

Comment: Yes I have copied above `index.hbs` and rerun the code but not getting WRAP_DATA

Comment: Also changes res.render to `res.render('index.hbs', {WRAP_DATA: WRAP_DATA});` but no change

Comment: Just to be clear. You won't get `WRAP_DATA` on your front-end. All you will get is the values such as `description` or `temp` populated in the table.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: That was the second option in the answer and involves quite a bit if extra work.